# Is there a way to know which USB device file (/dev/ttyUSB0) is related to a particular interface (wwan0)

Tags: linux, networking, usb, serial-port, udev

The title pretty much says it all, but here is my scenario in case it's relevant:

I'm trying to automate bringing a USB modem online when it's first plugged in. With my hardware and cellular service, when the wwan0 interface first connects, it will have a 169.254.x.x (unconnected) address. The corresponding modem needs to receive an "AT^NDISDUP=1,1" command via its device file before it will go live. I've written an if-up hook where I have access to the interface names of fresh connections, but I don't know how to link them to their corresponding device files.

I'm also open to hearing other ideas if this is impossible or just not a good way to do things. Thanks much.

***UPDATE***

As per Kamil's suggestion, I've dug into sysfs. I've found various device-related entries (/sys/devices/platform/.../.../ttyUSB0) and interface-related entries (/sys/class/net/wwan0) but I'm still failing to find a way to use one to obtain the other. I'm using udevadm to pull information from different entries, but I don't really understand what I'm looking at most of the time.

Comment: I'm not sure and I cannot test this right now (therefore this is not an answer) but if I were you I would dive in `/sys`. Start from `/sys/class/net/wwan0`.

Comment: Have you already ruled out letting ModemManager handle the process?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski - I'll look into /sys/class/net/ now. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @user1686 - I haven't tried ModemManager. I've just been working with the modems directly. Is ModemManager something that people generally use for this kind of thing?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski - I've followed your suggestion and dug around in sysfs. I've found directories for both devices (ttyUSB0) and interfaces (wwan0), but can't seem to find a connection linking the two. I've been checking info with udevadm, but coming up short.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using picocom v3 to acheive this using following script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

for tty in $(ls /dev/ttyUSB*); do
    echo "Checking $tty"
    picocom -qrX -b 9600 $tty
    sleep 1
    result=$(echo "AT&F" | picocom -qrix 1000 $tty)
    if [ "$result" = "AT&F" ]; then
        echo "Found AT compatible modem at $tty"
    else
        echo "No AT compatible modem at $tty"
    fi
done
```

You can replace `/dev/ttyUSB*` with whatever fits your modem device, but this one is pretty generic and should work.